# Comparing Raw I420 Video Files with Python

Tags: python

I want to write a programm that tells you if two given raw video files with 420 colorspace are frame identical. So far i have this:

```
import os
def checkifduplicate(file, file2, width, height):
bytesPerFrame = int(width * height * 12/8)
n1 = int(os.stat(file).st_size / bytesPerFrame)
n2 = int(os.stat(file2).st_size / bytesPerFrame)         
if (n1 != n2):
    return 0
with open (file, "rb") as f1:
    with open(file2, "rb") as f2:
        frameF1 = f1.read(bytesPerFrame)
        frameF2 = f2.read(bytesPerFrame)
        counter = 1
        while frameF1 != b"" and frameF2 != b"" and counter <= n1:
            if (frameF1 != frameF2):
                return 1
            frameF1 = f1.read(bytesPerFrame)
            frameF2 = f2.read(bytesPerFrame)
            counter += 1       
return 2

inputFile1 = "1.raw"
inputFile2 = "2.raw"
n = checkifduplicate(inputFile1,inputFile2,3840,2160)
if (n == 0):
  print ("Files contain different amounts of Frames... Ending")
elif (n == 1):
  print ("Different Frames")
elif (n == 2):
  print ("Identical Stream")
pause = input("Press a Key to End...")
```

If i use two raw files with different size it works properly.
Also if I use the same raw file twice it return 2 (identical stream)
If I copy one raw file tho and rename it and use those 2 files it returns 1 (different frame)